# Arabic text from oracle issue

Tags: php, oracle, encoding, arabic-support

when i render arabic text from my oracle DB it looks like this:

������� ������

even though i use windows-1256 encoding.

btw: arabic text that doesn't come from the DB is rendered correctly

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3647899

Comment: What do you mean by "even though i use windows-1256 encoding"? Did you set it for `NLS_LANG` or do you mean the database encoding or the encoding set in php?

Comment: sorry this is php issue

Comment: I don't see it as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through. Problem is related to Oracle not MySQL!

Comment: As the question has been closed, I recommend you to ask it again. It is definitely not a duplicate of linked question. Provide in your question also your database character set, your `NLS_LANG` value and the encoding you use in your tools.